# Meaning of 降ってくる when talking about voice

Tags: meaning, nuances, subsidiary-verbs

> 山田さんの声が後ろから**降ってきた**のだ。
>   山田's voice *came falling* from behind.

What is the nuance implied by 降る here?

Comment: It might also be pointing to the altitudinal difference between the two.(e.g.,  Yamada standing behind the speaker, who was sitting or lying)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. 後ろから山田さんの声がしたのだ。
> 2. 後ろから山田さんの声が聞こえたのだ。
> 3. 後ろから山田さんの声が降ってきたのだ。

Putting aside the fact that the sentence 3 is uncommon and a bit literary, the semantic nuance of the sentence 3, if any, is that the voice came *unexpectedly and suddenly*.

A figurative expression "空から降ってきたような話" means "sudden and unexpected offer". There's an idiomatic phrase [降って湧く](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/195911/meaning/m0u/) which means "(something) happens suddenly and unexpectedly".